# Android animation library for precise control over view movements

Tags: android, android-animation

I have accepted to help my friend in an android project of his, in which he needs to move several "line" views (like a vertical line 40 dp high) with dynamically changing speed. For example the line should start moving horizontally from the right edge of screen, at time = 0, with a speed equaling -1 / t (negative because it goes left!). 
Is there such a library that allows precise control over the animation kinematics? I look for external libraries because the XML or Android's native animation methods don't seem to be able to pull this off as far as I know. 
And if there is no such library, can I move the view manually in this fashion without creating much overhead/lag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be worth looking into [`Interpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) (or just [`TimeInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html) if you're targeting API 11+). These allow you to define the rate of change for an animation, enabling non-linear motions.

Comment: What @MH. said, in addition to use existing one, you can also implement your own Interpolator to provide the exact speed you need.